# Why does something get installed when I run my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxp

I followed the [tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3099751/Java-API-for-XML-Processing-JAXP-Getting-Started.htm) here:

and my classes are one.java and oneWriter.java

When I run one.java, my jar gets installed for some reason:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nZlBG.png

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Parpd.png

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "my jar gets installed"?

Comment: Please see the the screenshots. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Future reference: Use the "edit" link under the question & above the comments to make the appropriate changes, not the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library whose name is [Streaming API For XML - javax.xml.stream-1.0.1.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/1.0-2) is licensed with [COMMON DEVELOPMENT AND DISTRIBUTION LICENSE (CDDL) Version 1.0](https://www.oracle.com/sun/index.html).

So when you use this library, an aggreement window appears.